# Resolving an alias to a remote server

Tags: mount, remote, hostname, file-server

I have what I think is called an IP alias, which is used to access a Windows file server from a Unix server. The path on Unix looks something like:

```
/folder/file.txt
```

which is somehow resolved as:

```
\\server\folder\file.txt
```

This is used within an ftp command from a SAS program running on Unix. I know very little about Unix, but I believe the alias is configured on Unix itself (not by the SAS server). As a normal (non-root) user, is there a way of looking up this alias and seeing the IP address it refers to? Or even better, a list of aliases and their IP addresses?

Perhaps I'm using the wrong terminology? My Google searches have turned up command aliases, but otherwise I've found very little helpful information.

*(I originally asked this on SU, but didn't get an answer: https://superuser.com/q/561921/113542)*

Comment: @MichaelMrozek unfortunely it's too old to migrate now.

Comment: @Sathya Ah, yes, that feature is...awesome. Well, you guys can close or not I guess

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - Did my best to correct the situation. The answerer below copied his/her answer to the original question. Perhaps delete this one? This is a really clunky UX and its frustrating to have overlapping sites.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 It's fine, I forgot about the whole "can't migrate if the post is old thing", so reposting is pretty much all you could do if you wanted the question here

Answer (score 2):

Unix lets you mount filesystems, including remote filesystems, under directories on your system. This is similar to the way you can attach a remote filesystem as a drive on your windows machine, e.g. creating a Z: that refers to `\\server\folder`. Instead of using drive letters, we have directories that refer to filesystems. So `/folder` could be a remote mount of a shared folder on the Windows file server, i.e. `\\server\folder`. Run the `mount` command, it will show you currently mounted filesystems, including remote ones. Also, do `cat /etc/fstab` and look for a line like

```
//192.168.0.244/Public  /networkstorage cifs    rw,user,noauto,guest  0 0
```

where `//192.168.0.244/Public` stands for `\\192.168.0.244\Public` and `/networkstorage` is the "mountpoint", the place in the Unix filesystem where the remote filesystem is attached.

IP aliases are something entirely different. Command aliases are not what you want either.

Comment: Hey... so I accidentally made the mods mad by cross posting. Would you mind copy/pasting your answer to SU for me? ... I'll upvote it there as well, then delete this question. http://superuser.com/q/561921/113542

Comment: `mount` gave me a list, but it does not include the mounts that I use in the SAS program. I don't have access to /etc/fstab. Clearly I'll need to work this out with the admins. Thanks though.

Comment: Hi Cyborgx37, I copied it over. Good luck sorting your problem out, it is unusual that `mount` didn't give you what you needed.